# How to strike out an entire group of text

Tags: strikeout

I am using the command `\sout{some text}` to strike out a word or a sentence; However, I wanted to know if it is possible to strike out a group of text without having to use the braces `{` and `}`.

Something similar to what `{\color{red} some text}` is to `\textcolor{red}{some text}`, or something like `\begin{sout}` and `\end{sout}` (this doesn't work!)

Comment: Must it also handle text style and/or display style math automatically?

Comment: Hi Steven! Thank you for your answer. I do not need to strike out maths, but I need the keep paragraphs/fonts intact

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This uses a variation on my `censor` package to accomplish the strikeout, since the `\xblackout` macro of that package can work across paragraph boundaries (but not across math, which the OP clarified is not needed).

To make the `\xblackout` macro operate as an environment, I used the `environ` packages feature of `\BODY`.  Even so, I had to go through an intermediate macro `\soutrefunexp` in order to expand `\BODY` once, to make it digestible to `\xblackout`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ,censor,calc}
\NewEnviron{mysout}
 {\soutrefunexp{\BODY}}
%%%%%%%%%%%
\censorruleheight=.1ex %THICKNESS OF CENSOR RULE
\newlength\nextcharwidth
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@cenword[1]{%
  \setlength{\nextcharwidth}{\widthof{#1}}%
  \censorrule{\nextcharwidth}%
  \kern -\nextcharwidth%
  #1}
\makeatother
\newcommand\soutref[1]{\censorruledepth=.55ex\xblackout{#1}}
\newcommand\soutrefunexp[1]{\expandafter\soutref\expandafter{#1}}
%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
What is this?

Another paragraph.

\begin{mysout}
What is this?

Another paragraph.
\end{mysout}

What is this?

Another paragraph.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Replacing `\xblackout` with `\blackout` produces the following slightly different result:

[image]